# Use matrix as lookup table in R for vectors

Tags: r, matrix, lookup

I have columns

```
sex <- c(1, 2, 1)
age <- c(12, 13, 14)
```

and a lookup table

```
bmi_adipos_limit_table = array(c(24.77, 24.91, 25.02, 24.65, 24.92, 25.18), dim = c(4,2))
```

and woud like to do

```
bmi_adipos_limits <- magicFunction(age, sex)
```

with

```
bmi_adipos = c(24.77, 24.92, 25.02)
```

I tried

```
bmi_adipos = bmi_adipos_limits[age-11, sex]
```

which did not work (return value was what I would have expected from `bmi_adipos_limits[(age-11) X sex]`). So can someone give me a hint what this `magicFunction` I'm looking for is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `mapply`:

```
mysubsetter <- function(x, y) {
    bmi_adipos_limit_table[x-11, y]
} 

mapply(mysubsetter, age, ex)
# [1] 24.77 25.18 25.02
```